# Effects on Input Variable after Failed Input Stream

Tags: c++, gcc, iostream, cin

I was working on the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter numbers separated by whitespace (use -1 to quit): ";
  int i = 0;
  while (i != -1) {
    std::cin >> i;        
    std::cout << "You entered " << i << '\n';
  }
}
```

I know that using `while (std::cin >> i)` would have been better but I don't understand a specific occurrence.
If I provide an invalid input, the loop becomes infinite because the Input Stream enters a failbit state. My question is that what happens to the input variable `i`? In my case, it becomes 0 regardless of the previous value entered. Why does it change to 0 after an invalid input? Is this a predefined behaviour?

Comment: the input variables i.e the arguments to the streams are left unchanged if the input failed..

Comment: @Koushik Are they? They change to 0 in my case. That is what my question is. Why does it change and why 0?

Comment: It doesn't for me, it always shows the last number I entered. Tested in MSVC2012.

Comment: @Borgleader I'm using GCC 4.7.2 on Code::Blocks and it does change to 0 and enters an infinite loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get zero because you have a pre-C++11 compiler.  Leaving the input value unchanged on failure is new in the latest standard.  The old standard required the following:

> If extraction fails, **zero is written to value** and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt))

For gcc, you need to pass `-std=c++11` to the compiler to use the new behavior.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.7.2 and I am using the -std=c++11 flag in Code::Blocks. Is that version pre-C++11?

Comment: It wasn't until 4.8.1 that they claimed all C++11 features were in place.  It's very possible they hadn't implemented the change in behavior yet.

Comment: I think you're right. It didn't change for @Borgleader on VS2012 but it does for me. Thanks!