# Why is control + P leading to infinite loop in C++ (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, visual-studio-2013, infinite-loop

I've been programming for a while (in Prolog, Scheme, and a little bit in C), but I recently decided to brush up on my C++ knowledge.  I solved a problem that was meant to illustrate vectors.  It was essentially a project to create a database that creates a vector to temporarily store the various games that the user inputs into it, and removes the ones they don't want.  The code itself is running fine, not as pretty as scheme or Prolog could do it, but it works.

However, **I accidentally typed "Control P"** into the first prompt of the program and I got the strangest result: **it started an infinite loop.**  I tried it again with **"Control Z"** and I got the same result.  I haven't tried any other key combos, but I imagine that some others could be found.  It's not a super worrying problem, but I am curious to know why it's doing this.  Is it something about C++, or is it just Visual Studio?  Anyway, here's the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the Cpp Games Database!";

int x = 0;
string game = "";
vector <string> games;
vector <string>::const_iterator iter;
while (x != 4){
    cout<< "\n\nPlease choose from the list bellow to decide what you want to do:\n";
    cout<< "1. Add Games to the Database.\n"
        << "2. Remove Games from the Database.\n"
        << "3. List all the Games.\n"
        << "4. Exit.\n"
        << "\n(Type the number of your choice and hit return)\n";
    cin >> x;
    switch (x){
        case 1:
            game = "";
            do{
                cout << "\nPlease Input a Game (type esc to exit): ";
                cin >> game;
                games.push_back(game);
            } while (game != "esc");
            games.pop_back();
            break;

        case 2:
            game = "";
            do{
                cout << "\nPlease input the game you would like to remove(or type esc to exit): ";
                cin >> game;
                iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), game);
                if(iter != games.end())
                    games.erase(iter);
                else cout << "\nGame not found, try again please.\n";
            } while (game != "esc");
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\nYour Games are:\n";
            for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); iter++)
            {
                cout << endl << *iter << endl;
            }
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have refused to check the return value of your I/O operations and now you're paying the price.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not inputting valid data for `cin` it is stuck there waiting for the data to be reprocessed or discarded for new input.  You need to check your input and only accept valid data.  Essentially `cin` is keeping the original data it's given and continuously trying to process it.

Always verify your input and discard it if it's invalid.

Here is another answer on the same problem for some more insight (with source).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430697/1858323

Comment: The first part is correct, but the idea that compilers change values or worse is quite weird. What value would that refer to? How can a runtime problem be affected by the compiler, which isn't running at that time?

Comment: The compiler is not making changes during runtime.  Different versions of different compilers will have different effects on invalid data, such as changing the value to 0 and setting a failbit.  This behavior is set during compile time depending on versions etc.  However, some will just enter a failstate and continue to loop.  Please see link attached above to original answer.